# Calling Stored Procedure in Entity Framework Core with parameters not start with @ or #

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm writing a data layer based on ef-core 2.2, which need to be compatible with SqlServer and Oracle.

When calling a SP with complex data format (like binary) or output parameters, a SqlParameter instance need to be created. The name of the parameter is started with @ or #, based on the type of the database chosen.

How to avoid use the prefix @ or #, for database compatibility?

Thanks.

Comment: It's been too long since I did any significant work with EF, so I will only put this as a comment. When executing Sql from within C#, I have never had a need to prefix the parameter name in C#, only prefix the parameters in the Sql that gets executed, as per the Sql language rules for the database (MSSql, Oracle, MySQL) eg: _.Parameters.Add("myParam", myValue);_

Comment: `SqlParameter` indeed does not require the name to be prefixed with `@`. This prefix is required on the protocol level, but `SqlCommand` will fix up the name internally before execution if it doesn't start with `@`. (No idea how it works in EF.) Oracle will not accept a `SqlParameter` -- this type is specific to the SQL Server provider. If you want to be database-agnostic you'd want a `DbParameter`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in sql you have to use @ but in oracle you can remove it.
Working with parameter placeholders
The syntax for parameter placeholders depends on the data source. The .NET Framework data providers handle naming and specifying parameters and parameter placeholders differently. This syntax is customized to a specific data source, as described in the following table.

```
System.Data.SqlClient   Uses named parameters in the format @parametername.

System.Data.OleDb   Uses positional parameter markers indicated by a question mark (?).

System.Data.Odbc    Uses positional parameter markers indicated by a question mark (?).

System.Data.OracleClient    Uses named parameters in the format :parmname (or parmname).
```

You can find total description from this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types?view=netframework-4.8#working-with-parameter-placeholders